# source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate failed

Tags: anaconda3

anaconda version: 4.10.1. 
anaconda is installed with **root** in `/opt/anaconda3`.
another user **mingming** tries to `source /opt/anaconda3/bin/activate` and shell never return until `CTRL + C`. **mingming** has `rwx` access to all files and directories in `/opt/anaconda3`. I am trying to install anaconda with root and make all other users can use it to create their own environment.

[image]

I found out that `conda init` alternate `PATH` in an endless loop, but why this is happening?

[image]